# Any way to Central Administration?

Tags: central-administration

I've bought Sharepoint Host and the Servers are outside of my country. Is there anyway to enter to Central Administration?

Comment: This is an issue between you and your host. Ask them.

Answer (score 6):

Central Administration is accessible via the server and via a URL. If you don't have direct server access, then it should be available via URL, provided your host allows it. You'd need to contact them to get the URL for central administration.

Comment: And to access Central Administration Web site you must be a Farm Administrator or have access to the account that is a farm administrator. To access some CA level functionality the account you use to access CA Web site also needs to be part of the server's (the server CA is running on) Administrators group.